# Convert caracter line to "normal" text

Tags: converters

I will not be able to convert this character line into "normal" text.

Can you translate it for me?

\ud835\ude83\ud835\ude98\ud835\ude9e\ud835\ude8f\ud835\ude95\ud835\ude9e\ud835\ude8f\ud835\ude8f\ud835\udea2 \ud83c\udf68

Answer (score 0):

You can use an unicode 16 online translator like:
https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter

Comment:   is the answer